# Add Vue.js computed property to data gathered from a server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, knockout.js, vuejs2, async-await

Coming from Knockout.js, where you can simply create an observable everywhere by defining it, is there something similar in Vue.js?

```js
let vm = {
    someOtherVar: ko.observable(7),
    entries: ko.observableArray()
};

function addServerDataToEntries(data) {
    data.myComputed = ko.pureComputed(() => vm.someOtherVar() + data.bla);
    vm.entries.push(data);
}

addServerDataToEntries({ bla: 1 });
```

In my Vue.js project, I'm getting a list of objects from the server. For each of those objects, I want to add a computed property that I can use in a `v-if` binding. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the way Knockout does it but it sounds like a Vue computed.  Create a data object to hold your fetched data:

```js
data() {
  return {
    items: null
  }
}
```

Imagine fetching it in the `created` hook (or Vuex, wherever):

```js
async created() {
  const response = await axios.get(...);
  this.items = response.data;
}
```

Create your computed:

```js
computed: {
  itemsFormatted() {
    if (!this.items) return null;
    return this.items.map(item => {
      // Do whatever you want with the items
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/69mwhs51/) using this pattern where I'm loading some data and printing out a filtered result from it.  Let me know if I misunderstood what you're looking for.  (You can see the original fetched data in the console.)